# Collision detection on a static element with dynamically generated skewed and rotated elements on a 2D plane

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, polygon

I am developing a wheel spinner (think Wheel of Fortune) with a static selector.

The circle segments are generated by having a square element which is then skewed by X degrees depending on the amount of segments. Another square element with a completely rounded left and top side. The overlap is then displayed to make the segment.

Once the wheel is spun, I need the clicker to detect which segment is selected.

The question is, how do I determine the co-ordinates of the segment to determine if the clicker is inside a segment.

Edit to add code segment:

Segment Generation

```js
<div className="Segment-outer" style={{transform: "skewX(" + this.props.skewDegrees
+ "deg)"}}>
  <div className="Segment-inner" style={{transform: "skewX(-"
  + this.props.skewDegrees + "deg)"}}>
  </div>
</div>
```

Segments are held in the following div which is then rotated as shown.

```js
<div className="Spinwheel-holder" style={{transform: "translate(-50%, -50%) 
rotate(" + this.state.rotateDegrees + "deg)"}}>
```

Output (after Skewing and CSS) is this for five segments. Each segment gets thinner as more are added:

[image: Visualization]

Known Variables:

Top, Left, Right, Bottom, x, y, height, width

Further Edit:

At the moment, I am using this for the collision detection, which works but is not entirely accurate.

```js
collision = !(
  ((segmentRect.y + segmentRect.height) < (this.state.clickerLocation.y)) ||
  (segmentRect.y > (this.state.clickerLocation.y + this.state.clickerLocation.height)) ||
  ((segmentRect.x + segmentRect.width) < this.state.clickerLocation.x) ||
  (segmentRect.x > (this.state.clickerLocation.x + this.state.clickerLocation.width))
)
```

Comment: Could you please add a visualization with all the variables that you know?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Added, thanks for getting back to me